# Better Approach for Populating Tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

I am implementing a tableview which provides me results for a search query. Till now I am able to parse the response using SAX parser and obtain an array of dictionary objects. I need to make a server call everytime user taps on search. Hence, storing the result array in database is not an option. For the case when the Array with response objects is large. Following are the two approaches I could think of:

```
1. I should save each result (dictionary object) while parsing in local database and then   load the tableview when the request completes.

2. Load the tableview using the array of dictionary objects after the request completes
```

Which approach is better from memory and performance point of view, given the fact that my local database already handles other operations?

Comment: it depends upon your ablilty to handle either array or dictionary. U can use either of them.

Comment: @prince .. You got it wrong. It is about storing search results in local database or populating them with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Option no. 2 is the best way to go. Here you can save the response data in the dictionary. And you can reload the table as per the values in the dictionary. Saving the data each time in the database would slow down your search process and increase unnecessary overhead.